# Machine Learning: Predict set of numbers based on previous number

Tags: python, matlab, azure, machine-learning

I have a set of 5 numbers as input and it produces output of 4 numbers.  Need to find a model which can learn from the existing input/output and able to predict the numbers.

Comment: You need to add more information about the input. Is it sequential or not? The model you choose depends on that.

Comment: Input is non-sequential.  I am trying to reverse engineer a technical indicator, where it takes 5 values of price data as input and calculates 4 values.  Next value will be another 5 price points and it calculates next 4 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Go for **recurrent neural networks** or **LSTM** (Long-Short term memories). In simple terms, a feed-forward neural network simply produces output for given input based on the way it has figured out the relation between Input and Output while training, but it has no idea what the previous state (output) was, the basic idea is to recursively feed the output back to the input, i.e we make use of previous state of output along with current input as input to the neural network in a **feedback loop fashion**, so the output of neural network not only depends on the input but also on previous output. 
   LSTMs are being widely used for poetry generation, code-generation etc, your problem falls under the same domain.

Refer this link for more details: [LSTM](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)